# How to convert Android Native App into Hybrid using cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, hybrid

I am native app developer of Android and IOS. I am searching a way to convert "native android/IOS app" into "Hybrid" using cordova or any other hybrid framework.  may we do that? or need to develop from scratch.

Comment: there is no magical way to convert the app. You can only re-develop it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developer of android with java you can convert your code for switch to hybrid application but for ios its impossible also for other android native platforms and you should create application from scratch.